# Is there any performance reason to append an unused AUTO_INCREMENT column in MySQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, mysql-5.6, auto-increment

In my work environment, MySQL has some weird stuff with performance, and one of the other devs wanted me to research this situation before dropping a column that has the [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute.

**Scenario**

We have a table that has a FOREIGN KEY that is used to INDEX into it.  It also currently has a column with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute that is defined as a KEY, but that KEY is completely unused.

**Question**

Just wanting to confirm that MySQL is not doing something weird, and if having no column with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute on a table is going to slow things down.

**Consideration**

I would like to drop the unused `AUTO_INCREMENTed` column, and it seems highly likely this action can only speed things up for us.

Comment: Show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

(The following applies to all versions, but only to ENGINE=InnoDB.)

An InnoDB table always has a `PRIMARY KEY`:

1. You could specify one; else
2. A `UNIQUE` key with non-null column(s); else
3. A hidden 6-byte number.  (This number does not otherwise exist.)

If you remove your PK, then option 2 or 3 will kick in.  If option 3 kicks in, each row will be 2 bytes bigger -- assuming your id is a 4-byte `INT` now.  This is a tiny performance hit.

The data in the table is ordered according to the `PRIMARY KEY`:

- With `AUTO_INCREMENT` or the hidden key, new inserts are being "appended" to the table;
- With some other `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` key, the rows are inserted 'where they belong'.  This is a tiny bit less efficient.

When you need to do maintenance on the table, you often need a unique way to identify each row.  For this reason, alone, I advocate having a *visible*, explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.

Which is a "better" `PRIMARY KEY`:

- An `AUTO_INCREMENT`?
- A "natural" key made up of one or more columns that are naturally unique?

Answer:  It depends.  Since that is not the topic of your question, I will defer the elaboration to another Q&A.  Also, since the PK is an index, there could be performance considerations for indexing.

Comment: Not only each row will be 2 bytes wider - but every other index as well.

Comment: nice, thanks -- in this case I have a separate, unique key multi-column (both non-null), in the table, so it sounds like I should be able to just drop the auto_increment -- in this case I think that is a better solution for us.

Comment: That's _usually_ what I would do.  There are other considerations I have not listed yet.  (Length of columns, existence of secondary indexes, etc.)  About 2/3 of the tables I have created have a 'natural' PK, not AI.